# Efficient way of frequency counting of continuous words?

Tags: python, string, parsing, text

I have a string like this:

```
inputString = "this is the first sentence in this book the first sentence is really the most interesting the first sentence is always first"
```

and a dictionary like this:

```
{   
   'always first': 0,
    'book the': 0,
    'first': 0,
    'first sentence': 0,
    'in this': 0,
    'interesting the': 0,
    'is always': 0,
    'is really': 0,
    'is the': 0,
    'most interesting': 0,
    'really the': 0,
    'sentence in': 0,
    'sentence is': 0,
    'the first': 0,
    'the first sentence': 0,
    'the first sentence is': 0,
    'the most': 0,
    'this': 0,
    'this book': 0,
    'this is': 0
}
```

What is the most efficient way of updating the frequency counts of this dictionary in one pass of the input string (if it is possible)? I get a feeling that there must be a parser technique to do this but am not an expert in this area so am stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm.

Comment: That is a very cool algorithm. Daunting to implement, though!

Comment: @Tom: There seems to be a Python implementation: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ahocorasick/0.9

Comment: +1 Wow... Seems exactly like what I want. Thanks a ton for this!

Answer (score 2):

When confronted with this problem, I think, "I know, I'll use regular expressions".

Start off by making a list of all the patterns, sorted by decreasing length:

```
patterns = sorted(counts.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)
```

Now make that into a single massive regular expression which is an alternation between each of the patterns:

```
allPatterns = re.compile("|".join(patterns))
```

Now run that pattern over the input string, and count up the number of hits on each pattern as you go:

```
pos = 0
while (True):
    match = allPatterns.search(inputString, pos)
    if (match is None): break
    pos = match.start() + 1
    counts[match.group()] = counts[match.group()] + 1
```

You will end up with the counts of each of the strings.

(An aside: i believe most good regular expression libraries will compile a large alternation over fixed strings like this using the Aho-Corasick algorithm that e.dan mentioned. Using a regular expression library is probably the easiest way of applying this algorithm.)

With one problem: where a pattern is a prefix of another pattern (eg 'first' and 'first sentence'), only the longer pattern will have got a count against it. This is by design: that's what the sort by length at the start was for.

We can deal with this as a postprocessing step; go through the counts, and whenever one pattern is a prefix of another, add the longer pattern's counts to the shorter pattern's. Be careful not to double-add. That's simply done as a nested loop:

```
correctedCounts = {}
for donor in counts:
    for recipient in counts:
        if (donor.startswith(recipient)):
            correctedCounts[recipient] = correctedCounts.get(recipient, 0) + counts[donor]
```

That dictionary now contains the actual counts.

Comment: you can write: `patterns = sorted(counts.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)`

Comment: @tokland: I didn't know that. I'll edit that into the answer, thanks.

Comment: @TomAnderson: +1 Thank you very much for this. Works very nice. However, I seem to be having some trouble in that I get this error message: `OverflowError: regular expression code size limit exceeded` Would you happen to know any workaround for this?

Comment: @Legend: Yes. Use fewer or shorter patterns! Sadly, i don't know useful way around that. You could try to rewrite the regular expression to make it smaller (by finding common prefixes); i don't know if that would actually help.

Answer (score 2):

The [Aho–Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) seems definitely the way to go, but if I needed a simple Python implementation, I'd write:

```
import collections

def consecutive_groups(seq, n):
    return (seq[i:i+n] for i in range(len(seq)-n))

def get_snippet_ocurrences(snippets):
    split_snippets = [s.split() for s in snippets]
    max_snippet_length = max(len(sp) for sp in split_snippets)
    for group in consecutive_groups(inputString.split(), max_snippet_length):
        for lst in split_snippets:
            if group[:len(lst)] == lst:
                yield " ".join(lst)

print collections.Counter(get_snippet_ocurrences(snippets))
# Counter({'the first sentence': 3, 'first sentence': 3, 'the first': 3, 'first': 3, 'the first sentence is': 2, 'this': 2, 'this book': 1, 'in this': 1, 'book the': 1, 'most interesting': 1, 'really the': 1, 'sentence in': 1, 'is really': 1, 'sentence is': 1, 'is the': 1, 'interesting the': 1, 'this is': 1, 'the most': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) or [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store words instead of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the string and use the dictionary as you would normally to increment any occurance. This is O(n), since dictionary lookup is often O(1). I do this regularly, even for large word collections.